# How can I make a passphrase-protected PPK stop asking for password in TortoiseHG via TortoisePlink and KeyRing

Tags: mercurial, ssh, tortoisehg, pageant

**SOLVED, see the last edit**

I have a SourceForge repository and I correctly set my SSH key there. It works fine. But when I use TortoiseHG to push my modifications to the repository, I keep getting asked for the password for my PPK (since I protected it).

I tell Mercurial about my PPK like this:

[ui]
ssh = tortoiseplink.exe -ssh -i "c:\Users\my_user\SSH\my_user.ppk"

But it keeps pestering me with the password for the PPK. I know about that KeyRing extension for Mercurial but does it work with PPKs?

Then...

There is this Pageant tool with TortoiseHG. Apparently you tell TortoiseHG to use it by specifying -agent, like this:

[ui]
ssh = tortoiseplink.exe -ssh -i "c:\Users\my_user\SSH\my_user.ppk" -agent

I added my key in Pageant but when I synchronize with TortoiseHG, it **still** asks for the passphrase of my PPK, even though I already mentioned that when I added the PPK in Pageant.

And another thing which annoys me is that Pageant "forgets" all keys upon program restart. So it's kinda' useless.

Any way I could use that KeyRing extension to add my PPK in TortoiseHG and keep the password stored somewhere?

If there is no way to solve this, I guess I'll just use a non-protected PPK and that's it...

**LATER EDIT:**

This is the debug output I get when I try to do a push via the TortoiseHG Sync tool, configured as above.

% hg --repository C:\Projects\MyProject push --debug ssh://echysttas@hg.code.sf.net/p/myproject/code

`pushing to ssh://echysttas@hg.code.sf.net/p/myproject/code`

`running "c:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -agent echysttas@hg.code.sf.net "hg -R p/myproject/code serve --stdio"`

`sending hello command`

`sending between command`

*here I get a password request, which I cancel because I don't want to keep repeating my password*

no suitable response from remote hg
[command returned code 255 Mon Nov 19 20:43:14 2012]

**LATER EDIT 2:**

I noticed that some examples use plink.exe instead of TortoisePlink.exe. Well, ok, I tried with plink.exe (directly from the Putty website) as well. This yielded promising results...

`sending hello command`

`sending between command`

`remote: Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20121118":`

`remote: Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20121118":`

But then, it got stuck here.

**LATER EDIT 3**

Amazingly funny find ::- D.

It got stuck because I was invoking TortoiseHG Sync from non-elevated Explorer but I started Pageant from an **elevated Total Commander**. I'm using UAC on my Windows 7 and that caused the problem.

If Pageant is run from admin-rights Total Commander, then the TrtoiseHG Sync must also be launched from there! If done so, it works! It also works if I start Pageant from non-elevated Explorer and I also do the Sync from there.

Done!

Lazy Badger I'm still awarding the answer to you because you were anything BUT lazy and you proved interest & helped me a lot. Although "it works on my machine" isn't really the answer, it sure got me thinking and your many words & descriptions are worth that glorious green checkmark, eh? :D.

Comment: Password request, according to SF docs means "You haven't SSH keys in profile"

Comment: Nah, password request also occurs if you try to commit without using plink. Then, you can do it with your usual SF password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I **can** work with pageant without being asked about password more one once

my ssh line

```
ssh = "c:\Program Files\_Tools\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe"
```

and running Pageant (with loaded private key /PuTTY-User-Key-File/) will give me ability to communicate with repo without re-authentication

**Note 1:** Keyring doesn't help in your case at all, debug pageant functionality with pure-ssh connection (ssh or plink)

**Note 2:** To start Pageant with key (only password needed) you can use extended [command-line](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant-cmdline-loadkey)

> Pageant can automatically load one or more private keys when it starts up, if you provide them on the Pageant command line. Your command line might then look like:
>
> `C:\PuTTY\pageant.exe d:\main.ppk d:\secondary.ppk`
>
> If the keys are stored encrypted, Pageant will request the passphrases on startup.
>
> If Pageant is already running, this syntax loads keys into the existing Pageant.

### Add-on

Tried push with my current ssh-settings for TortoiseHG 2.6 (XP SP3 x86), [Mercurial repo](https://sourceforge.net/u/bigbadger/code/)

```
c:\TEMP\Fiver>hg push sf
pushing to ssh://bigbadger@hg.code.sf.net/u/bigbadger/code
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 7 changesets with 39 changes to 19 files
remote: <Repository /hg/u/bigbadger/code> refresh queued.
```

Local repo hgrc

```
[paths]
...
sf = ssh://bigbadger@hg.code.sf.net/u/bigbadger/code
```

Private key loaded into Pageant, public key registered on SF, in my profile

Mercurial.ini (relevant part)

```
[ui]
merge = <irrelevant>
username = <irrelevant>
ssh = "c:\Program Files\_Tools\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe"
```

(note none of additional arguments for TortoisePlink)

and **nothing** *more special* was done

**Screenshot of pure THG push with log output**

[image: Push]

Log of *good plink+pageant session* for SF-SSH

```
>Plink.exe -v -agent bigbadger@hg.code.sf.net
Looking up host "hg.code.sf.net"
Connecting to 216.34.181.156 port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 86:7b:1b:12:85:35:8a:b7:98:b6:d2:97:5e:96:58:1d
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Using username "bigbadger".
Trying Pageant key #0
Authenticating with public key "github/lazybadger" from agent
Sending Pageant's response
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
Last login: Tue Nov 20 03:20:48 2012 from 85.249.33.17
Server sent command exit status 1
Disconnected: All channels closed

Welcome to hg.sourceforge.net
This is a restricted Shell Account
You cannot execute anything here.
```

Comment: TortoisePlink works for me as well. As in, I don't get a request from SourceForge for my password, but I do get a request to enter the private key passphrase. So it appears that Pageant just doesn't work. It seems like it's not actually connected to TortoiseHG.

Comment: @Axonn - Try to `push --debug` from CLI in order to see more details: I can push (have to repeat) to git+ssh:// from THG+Pageant

Comment: This is what the debug returns. It's weird that it sends that echysttas@hg.code.sf to the agent. echysttas is my SF user. Maybe that's ok. Here comes the debug data: ssh://echysttas@hg.code.sf.net/p/magebook/code
running "c:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -agent echysttas@hg.code.sf.net "hg -R p/magebook/code serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
no suitable response from remote hg

Comment: @Axonn - please, **full** real output - you may add it into question

Comment: That's almost all the output. It's obtained from the TortoiseHG Sync tool (Windows 7 x64). I added the output full to the question.

Comment: @Axonn - check https://sourceforge.net/account/services, "Number of SSH Shared Keys (Public Keys)" and using correct private key (private key is pair for loaded public key)

Comment: Yes, it works and it's correct. If I enter the passphrase for the private key, then the commit works. I discovered one more thing in the meantime, which I added as 2nd later edit to my question.